# Apply precision and scale to python float object?

Tags: python, decimal

I am new to python programming,
i want to convert my input float number to become output as precision as 10 or less(total digits in number) and scale as 1 (numbers after decimal point). how can i achieve it in python.

```
>>> float(raw_input("Enter price:"))
User price:6738882993.98888888373333
6738882993.988889
>>>
```

Thanks

Hema

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/981189/python-printing-floats-modifying-the-output

Answer (score 0):

In order to have that you need the [decimal](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html) type, not the float type.